# How to delete the unused files in past commits

Tags: git

I have git repository.

I wrongly git the unnecesary big files a few times,so file size is quite big.

```
$du -sh .git/objects
1.3G    .git/objects
```

I want to delete the past unnecesary files.

So, I checked the unused big files [with this script](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/maintain-a-git-repository/)

```
$sh git_find_big.sh
All sizes are in kB's. The pack column is the size of the object, compressed, inside the pack file.
-e         size       pack                                      SHA                                                            location
810409984  495862913  4bb4caef2a85833bdf6f00bb9d85336db461c0f9  w2v_model/chive-1.2-mc90.magnitude
578685728  537201063  3f99a664faebd9230183c41d07afd82ca00ca798  w2v_model/chive-1.2-mc90_gensim/chive-1.2-mc90.kv.vectors.npy
223313372  89641673   ff6eabe882f56f49756e00ed09b36e872bd522ee  w2v_model/ja/ja.tsv
60129680   55860848   efd88223905b1c814fd3799dbb29a76c7f5cfd73  w2v_model/ja/ja.bin.syn1neg.npy
60129680   55853784   ffc4ab2e30bc8ffec6f6c024ac2003b78fc5e72d  w2v_model/ja/ja.bin.syn0.npy
57033294   54522375   a83910c4160775c3c9cb09f61ce0e53ecb2dca8e  static/defapp/assets/accompaniment.wav
```

then , I think `w2v_model/chive-1.2-mc90.magnitude` is not necessary.

So, I try like this,

```
$git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch w2v_model/chive-1.2-mc90.magnitude' -- --all

WARNING: git-filter-branch has a glut of gotchas generating mangled history
     rewrites.  Hit Ctrl-C before proceeding to abort, then use an
     alternative filtering tool such as 'git filter-repo'
     (https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/) instead.  See the
     filter-branch manual page for more details; to squelch this warning,
     set FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1.
Proceeding with filter-branch...

Cannot rewrite branches: You have unstaged changes.
```

However after this, file size is not changed.

```
$du -sh .git/objects
1.3G    .git/objects
```

How can I delete the unused file in past commit?

---

Thanks for your comment after I push unstagged comment,

git filter-branch works.

```
$git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch w2v_model' -- --all  
WARNING: git-filter-branch has a glut of gotchas generating mangled history
     rewrites.  Hit Ctrl-C before proceeding to abort, then use an
     alternative filtering tool such as 'git filter-repo'
     (https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/) instead.  See the
     filter-branch manual page for more details; to squelch this warning,
     set FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1.
Proceeding with filter-branch...

Rewrite 01787ee7aec64ee385de2127c23d08fb3ab2c9c8 (76/149) (7 seconds passed, remaining 6 predicted)    rm 'w2v_model/.DS_Store'
rm 'w2v_model/ja/ja.bin'
```

then ,

```
$git reflog expire --expire=now --all

$git gc --prune=now
```

file size is changed.

```
du -sh .git/objects                 
343M    .git/objects
```

Comment: Relevant chapter from the Git Book: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery

Comment: Your filter-branch failed: `Cannot rewrite branches: You have unstaged changes.`

Comment: Thank you I push the commit  and `filter-branch` looks works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Clean your working directory first! Discard or commit unstaged changes.
2. Do not use filter-branch. It is depredecated. Use filter-repo

```bash
git filter-repo --path "path/to/file" --invert-paths --force
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer somwhoe I cant use filter-repo though, step 1 works well.

Comment: What is the problem?
https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md